# Adding Colorbar to a Spectrogram

Tags: python, python-2.7, spectrogram

I'm trying to add a Colorbar to a spectrogram. I have tried every example and question thread I have found online and none have solved this issue

Note that 'spl1' (data splice 1) is a trace from ObsPy.

**My code is:**

```
fig = plt.figure()
ax1 = fig.add_axes([0.1, 0.75, 0.7, 0.2]) #[left bottom width height]
ax2 = fig.add_axes([0.1, 0.1, 0.7, 0.60], sharex=ax1)
ax3 = fig.add_axes([0.83, 0.1, 0.03, 0.6])

t = np.arange(spl1[0].stats.npts) / spl1[0].stats.sampling_rate
ax1.plot(t, spl1[0].data, 'k')

ax,spec = spectrogram(spl1[0].data,spl1[0].stats.sampling_rate, show=False, axes=ax2)
ax2.set_ylim(0.1, 15)
fig.colorbar(spec, cax=ax3)
```

It comes out with the error:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):

  File "<ipython-input-18-61226ccd2d85>", line 14, in <module>
    ax,spec = spectrogram(spl1[0].data,spl1[0].stats.sampling_rate, show=False, axes=ax2)

TypeError: 'Axes' object is not iterable
```

**Best result so far:**

Replacing the last 3 lines above with:

```
ax = spectrogram(spl1[0].data,spl1[0].stats.sampling_rate, show=False, axes=ax2)
ax2.set_ylim(0.1, 15)
fig.colorbar(ax,cax=ax3)
```

Produces this:
[image: Waveform and spectrogram plot]

and this error for the colorbar:

```
axes object has no attribute 'autoscale_None'
```

I don't seem to be able to find a way to get the colorbar on the right to work.

**Solutions?**

One of the solutions I have seen is that you need to create an 'image' of your data using imshow(), however I don't get an output for that from Spectrogram(), only 'ax'. I have seen places try with the 'ax,spec' output from spectrogram() but that is causing the TypeError.

- Very similar code I found but didn't work https://www.nicotrebbin.de/wp-content/uploads/2012/03/bachelorthesis.pdf (ctrl+f 'colorbar')
- Looked at code examples [from a related question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20053840/error-while-attempting-to-add-color-bar)
- imshow() [suggestions](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13784201/matplotlib-2-subplots-1-colorbar) and [example](http://docs.obspy.org/tutorial/code_snippets/continuous_wavelet_transform.html) - can't get an output from spectrogram to turn into an image. That second link, I also can't get the mlpy module to work (it doesn't think there's a mlpy.wavelet function)
- This problem was addressed in [an improvement post for obspy](https://github.com/obspy/obspy/issues/1086) but the solution he stated he found was not given

I hope someone can give a hand with this - I've been working on this all day now!

Comment: Have you successfully plotted a spectrogram without a colorbar? What is the ``spectrogram`` function (from which library) you are using?

Comment: @gsmafra I have updated the post above with more info - I can get the spectrogram to plot normally yes. The spectrogram function is from: obspy.imaging.spectrogram.spectrogram (as it has simpler built-in functionality) - although underneath it uses specgram

Comment: ongoing discussion in: https://github.com/obspy/obspy/issues/1086 which has a successful colorbar plot. Doesn't work for my situation but if a solution is found there then I'll add the solution here too.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Solved it, with help from [this link](https://github.com/obspy/obspy/issues/1086). It doesn't show decibels yet but the primary issue was getting the colorbar:

```
from obspy.imaging.spectrogram import spectrogram
fig = plt.figure()
ax1 = fig.add_axes([0.1, 0.75, 0.7, 0.2]) #[left bottom width height]
ax2 = fig.add_axes([0.1, 0.1, 0.7, 0.60], sharex=ax1)
ax3 = fig.add_axes([0.83, 0.1, 0.03, 0.6])

#make time vector
t = np.arange(spl1[0].stats.npts) / spl1[0].stats.sampling_rate

#plot waveform (top subfigure)    
ax1.plot(t, spl1[0].data, 'k')

#plot spectrogram (bottom subfigure)
spl2 = spl1[0]
fig = spl2.spectrogram(show=False, axes=ax2)
mappable = ax2.images[0]
plt.colorbar(mappable=mappable, cax=ax3)
```

[image: produced figure]