# matplotlib colorbar not working (due to garbage collection?)

Tags: python, matplotlib, garbage-collection, ipython

I have a plotting function similar to this one

```
def fct():
    f=figure()
    ax=f.add_subplot(111)
    x,y=mgrid[0:5,0:5]
    z=sin(x**2+y**2)
    ax.pcolormesh(x,y,z)
```

When I define the function above in `ipython` (using the `--pylab` option), and then call

```
fct()
colorbar()
```

I get an error

> "RuntimeError: No mappable was found to use for colorbar creation.".

```
def fct():
    f=figure()
    x,y=mgrid[0:5,0:5]
    z=sin(x**2+y**2)
    pcolormesh(x,y,z)
```

Then it works. I guess this has to do with garbage collection - how can I prevent this problem in the first example?

Comment: The second answer may be relevant: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2643953/attributeerror-while-adding-colorbar-in-matplotlib

Answer (score 20, accepted):

It is because you first example, you are using `ax.polormesh`, not `pyplot.polotmesh` (namespace imported by `pylab`), when you call `colorbar()` (actually `plt.colorbar()`), it lost track of which mappable and which ax it should make colorbar to.

Therefore adding these lines will make it work:

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
fct()
ax=plt.gca() #get the current axes
PCM=ax.get_children()[2] #get the mappable, the 1st and the 2nd are the x and y axes
plt.colorbar(PCM, ax=ax)
```

[image]

Now you mentioned that your actual plot is a much more complex one. You want to make sure it is the `ax.get_children()[2]` or you can pick the it by look for a `matplotlib.collections.QuadMesh` instance.

Comment: In my case the plot was more complex, to find the correct child I had to do: `for PCM in ax.get_children():
            if type(PCM) == matplotlib.image.AxesImage:
                break`

Comment: I can remove the color bar in this way, but the numbers next to the color bar are still there. Is there any way to remove them too?

Answer (score 9):

I think it has more to do with the `pylab` state machine and scoping.

A better practice would be to do the following (explicit is better than implicit):

```
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

def fct():
    f = plt.figure()
    ax = f.add_subplot(111)
    x, y = np.mgrid[0:5,0:5]
    z = np.sin(x**2+y**2)
    mesh = ax.pcolormesh(x, y ,z)

    return ax, mesh

ax, mesh = fct()
plt.colorbar(mesh, ax=ax)
```

Answer (score 5):

You function is quite small and takes no arguments, so do you really need to wrap the plotting in a function? What about:

```
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

fig, ax = plt.subplots(1, 1)
x, y = np.mgrid[0:5,0:5]
z = np.sin(x**2+y**2)
mesh = ax.pcolormesh(x, y ,z)
fig.colorbar(mesh)
plt.show()
```

[image]

Comment: my function was just a minimum working example. The actual plotting function is much more complicated and gets called repeatedly, so I only want to write it once.

Answer (score 2):

For me the following code did not work

```
PCM=ax.get_children()[2] 
plt.colorbar(PCM, ax=ax)
```

since my plot was a little bit more complicated I had to go with the following code based on the comment by @lib.

```
ax=plt.gca() #get the current axes
for PCM in ax.get_children():
    if isinstance(PCM, mpl.cm.ScalarMappable):
        break
        
plt.colorbar(PCM, ax=ax)
```