# color bar issue with cartopy, 'GeoAxesSubplot' object has no attribute 'get_array'

Tags: geopandas, colorbar, cartopy

I'm using `pandas`, `geopandas`, and `cartopy` to make spatial plots for data points.

Everything works fine, except for when I try to add color bar.

Below is my code and the error. Any help is appreciated.

```
fig = plt.figure()

ax = plt.axes(projection=ccrs.PlateCarree())

reader = shpreader.Reader('countyl010g.shp')

counties = list(reader.geometries())

COUNTIES = cfeature.ShapelyFeature(counties, ccrs.PlateCarree())

ax.add_feature(COUNTIES, facecolor='none', edgecolor='gray')

ax.coastlines()

ax.add_feature(cartopy.feature.STATES)


dp=pd.read_csv('Arash.csv',index_col=False)

def remove_minutes(state):
  state=datetime.datetime.strptime(state, '%Y-%m-%d %H:%M:%S')
  state= state.replace(minute=0)
  return state

dp['TIMESTAMP']=dp['TIMESTAMP'].apply(remove_minutes)

dp.set_index(['TIMESTAMP'], inplace=True)

dp= dp[dp.index.day == 28]

dp['coordinates'] = dp[['Longitude', 'Latitude']].values.tolist()

dp['coordinates'] = dp['coordinates'].apply(Point)

dp = gpd.GeoDataFrame(dp, geometry='coordinates')

ac=dp.plot(ax=ax,column='CO_CMAQ',markersize=0.05,cmap='turbo')

ax.set_xlim(-119,-117)

ax.set_ylim(33.5,34.5)

fig.colorbar(ac,ax=ax)
```

And here is the error:

> File "C:\Python-practice\GHG\spatial_plot_mobile.py", line 102, in
>  fig.colorbar(ac,ax=ax)
>
> File
> "C:\Users\akash\anaconda3\lib\site-packages\matplotlib\figure.py",
> line 2343, in colorbar cb = cbar.colorbar_factory(cax, mappable,
> **cb_kw)
>
> File
> "C:\Users\akash\anaconda3\lib\site-packages\matplotlib\colorbar.py",
> line 1734, in colorbar_factory cb = Colorbar(cax, mappable, **kwargs)
>
> File
> "C:\Users\akash\anaconda3\lib\site-packages\matplotlib\colorbar.py",
> line 1202, in **init**
>
> if mappable.get_array() is not None: AttributeError: 'GeoAxesSubplot'
> object has no attribute 'get_array'

Thank you again,

Comment: Any help on this is greatly appreciated.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Colorbar on Geopandas](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36008648/colorbar-on-geopandas)

Answer (score 1):

Old question, but I landed on it because I had an analogous error, so in case it helps anyone else in future:

The problem is that `ac` here is a GeoAxesSubplot object within a Matplotlib figure. When Matplotlib is given `fig.colorbar(ac,ax=ax)`, it doesn't know what to do with `ac`.

As per the [Geopandas documentation](https://geopandas.org/en/stable/docs/user_guide/mapping.html), the information about the colorbar needs to go into the Geopandas `.plot()` itself, so that the relevant line above would look something like:

```
ac=dp.plot(ax=ax,column='CO_CMAQ',markersize=0.05,cmap='turbo', 
           legend=True, legend_kwds={'label':"",'orientation':""})
```

with the `legend_kwds` filled in as desired, e.g. `orientation="horizontal"`.

More advice on modifying Geopandas colorbars [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53158096/editing-colorbar-legend-in-geopandas).